# KVM, protocols for communication

Tags: virtual-machine, protocols, kvm

What protocols does KVM use to communicate with host machine? I'm trying to network analyzer but still it is not really clear.

Comment: You have to be more specific here.  Which communication are you referring to?  Did you find *anything* with the network analyzer?  Post that if you have it.

Comment: @GrishaLevit, I have only this kind of information  - acks and pushes of data. However, I would like like to know is there smth more special about there communication, can I install SSL certificate between them. I know, that this is done mainly between two host or two clients machine, but anyway.